# NestJs socket Io works on a different port but not the same port

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I am trying to implement socket Io into an application. However nestjs `WebSocketGateway` doesnt seem to get triggered when the port isnt defined. However when using a different port for `WebSocketGateway` the frontend connects succesfully.

This works

```
@WebSocketGateway(8001, {
  path: '/socket-chat',
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
})
```

This doesnt work

```
@WebSocketGateway({
  path: '/socket-chat',
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
})
```

When using the same port as the API, the middleware gets triggered however it seems to be working and sucessfully passing the request. I would like to use the same port but not sure how. Thank you :)

Comment: Same here. I wasn't able to connect my client and I was struggling with that. I set up a different port and it worked just fine. Your question helped me yet it isn't perfect

Answer (score 4):

`WebSocketGateway` works just fine when passing zero as the port. It will use the same port you defined in the server.

```js
@WebSocketGateway(0, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
})
```

Comment: I couldn't believe that this answer got 3 upvotes, but it actually worked. We tried so many things, but your answer fixed it. Thanks!